# Как удалить зазубренный край при использовании маски в QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qpainter, qpixmap

В настоящее время я пытаюсь поместить изображение в виде маски в `QPushButton`.

Проблема, которая возникает, состоит в том, что по краям есть граница, похожая на неровное прикрепленное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на верхних краях, такой проблемы нет, они гладкие и постоянные, но на боковых краях это выглядит неравномерно.

Это код, который я использовал:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.resize(300,50)
        self.image = QPixmap("button.png")
        self.image = self.image.scaled(200,50)#50,50
        self.button.setMask(self.image.mask())
        self.button.setStyleSheet("Background:blue;border:1px solid  black")


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

---

Это изображение, которое я использую в качестве маски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, изображение не имеет этой проблемы. 
Я надеюсь, что вы можете мне помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выбрали **плохое изображение**, для использования в качестве маски.
Это не параллелограмм. Параллелограмм - это четырёхугольник, у которого противоположные стороны попарно параллельны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Painter - не может сгладить края данного изображения одинаково.
Если немного поиграть с размерами кнопки, то можно сгладить только один край.

Покликайте кнопку и вы все увидите.
Измените размеры окна и посмотрите как отрисовывается выбранное вами изображение.

**Вывод вам нужно другое изображение для получения желаемого результата.**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self) # self 
#        self.button.resize(300,50)
        self.button.resize(242,35)  

        self.image = QPixmap("button.png") 
        self.image = self.image.scaled(242,35)            # (200,50)  50,50  

        self.button.setMask(self.image.mask())

        self.button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: yellow; 
                border: 1px solid red; 
            }
            QPushButton:pressed {background-color: green;}
        """)

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("button.png")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.TextAntialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)    
        print("rect-> ", self.rect())    
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap) 

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.pixmap.size()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    m.resize(987, 150)   # (800, 600)  
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]